# How to save cluster assignments and prevent them from being overwritten in next iterations when calculating the bias?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, fairness-indicators

I'm implementing an algorithm that calculates the bias per cluster and then splits the cluster with the highest bias into new clusters. Eventually, I want to find the cluster with the highest bias, which means that the classifier either produced more errors on these instances, or substantially less errors.

This is the algorithm:

1. Start with whole dataset as one cluster
2. Split into two clusters with KMeans
3. Calculate the macro F1-score for each of these clusters
4. Calculate the bias for both of these clusters. The bias is:
   F1-score_cluster_k - F1-score all clusters excluding cluster k
5. if Max(bias_cluster_i, bias_cluster_j) >= bias_previous_cluster:
   add the clusters cluster_i and cluster_j to the list and remove the previous cluster
6. Proceed with the cluster from the cluster_list which has the highest standard deviation of the error metric.
7. Split this cluster into 2 clusters with KMeans and proceed with step 3

To make this algorithm work, I need to save the cluster assignments and the F-scores from the previous iterations to be able to compare them in the current iteration (step 5).

- One of my solutions is to save the cluster assignments in a Pandas DF as a new column and then compare this column with the new cluster assignments, but is there a better way of preventing these cluster assignments from being overwritten?

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine

data = load_wine()
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
df_target = pd.DataFrame(data = data.target)

# Merging the datasets into one dataframe
all_data = df_data.merge(df_target, left_index=True, right_index=True)
all_data.rename( columns={0 :'target_class'}, inplace=True )
all_data.head()

# Dividing X and y into train and test data (small train data to gain more errors)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_data, df_target, test_size=0.60, random_state=2)

# Training a RandomForest Classifier 
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())

# Obtaining predictions
y_hat = model.predict(X_test)

# Converting y_hat from Np to DF
predictions_col = pd.DataFrame()
predictions_col['predicted_class'] = y_hat.tolist()
predictions_col['true_class'] = y_test

# Calculating the errors with the absolute value 
predictions_col['errors'] = abs(predictions_col['predicted_class'] - predictions_col['true_class'])

# It doesn't matter whether the misclassification is between class 0 and 2 or between 0 and 1, it has the same error value. 
predictions_col['errors'] = predictions_col['errors'].replace(2.0, 1.0)

# Adding predictions to test data
df_out = pd.merge(X_test, predictions_col, left_index = True, right_index = True)

# Scaling the features
scaled_matrix = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df_matrix)

# Calculating the errors of the instances in the clusters.
def F_score(results, class_number):
    true_pos = results.loc[results["true_class"] == class_number][results["predicted_class"] == class_number]
    true_neg = results.loc[results["true_class"] != class_number][results["predicted_class"] != class_number]
    false_pos = results.loc[results["true_class"] != class_number][results["predicted_class"] == class_number]
    false_neg = results.loc[results["true_class"] == class_number][results["predicted_class"] != class_number]
    
    try:
        precision =  len(true_pos)/(len(true_pos) + len(false_pos))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0
    try:
        recall = len(true_pos)/(len(true_pos) + len(false_neg))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

    f_score = 2 * ((precision * recall)/(precision + recall))

    return f_score

# Calculating the macro average F-score
def mean_f_score(results):
    n_classes = results['true_class'].unique()
    class_list = []
    for i in range(0, n_classes-1):
        class_i = F_score(results, i)
        class_list.append(class_i)
   
    mean_f_score = (sum(class_list))/n_classes
    
    return(mean_f_score)

def calculate_bias(clustered_data, cluster_number):
    cluster_x = clustered_data.loc[clustered_data["assigned_cluster"] == cluster_number]
    remaining_clusters = clustered_data.loc[clustered_data["assigned_cluster"] != cluster_number]
    
    # Bias definition:
    return mean_f_score(remaining_clusters) - mean_f_score(cluster_x)

MAX_ITER = 10
cluster_comparison = []

# start with all instances in one cluster
# scaled_matrix
for i in range(1, MAX_ITER):
    kmeans_algo = KMeans(n_clusters=2, **clus_model_kwargs).fit(scaled_matrix) 
    clustered_data = pd.DataFrame(kmeans_algo.predict(scaled_matrix), columns=['assigned_cluster']) 
# Adding the assigned cluster to the column 
    # groups = pd.DataFrame(cluster_model.predict(df_data),columns=["group"])
    
    # Calculating bias per cluster
    for cluster in clustered_data:
        negative_bias_0 = calculate_bias(clustered_data, 0)
        negative_bias_1 = calculate_bias(clustered_data, 1)
    # the code below doesn't work
    if max(negative_bias_0, negative_bias_1) >= bias_prev_iteration:
```

Comment: can you please reduce the code to the essential parts?

Comment: I tried to run it and it keeps returning errors everywhere

Comment: for example some parts of your code uses `predicted_class` and others use `assigned_cluster` as input.. putting these together isn't going to work